# Social networks notifications in a C# application

Tags: c#, windows, facebook, desktop-application

I'm planning to write an application in c# in visual stuio 2013 that will allow a facebook user to login and receive their facebook notifications straight to the desktop as popups. Ive searched around and cannot seem to find whether or not it is possible to get notifications from facebook as soon as they happen and react to them in a suitable way, i'm wondering if this is possible and which bits of the api/ sdk i would need to use to get this to work.
Thanks in advance,
Alistair

Answer (score 0):

Reading from the Facebook Developer's page(https://developers.facebook.com/), there isn't any specific SDK to C#, for desktop applications
. 
But there is a SDK for Javascript, maybe a web application can be an option for you.